# How retrieve Metadata from each blob in my Azure container?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am having trouble accessing the metadata from the Azure container that I have created. There are 2 keys with 2 values, the first metadata is {key: cellNumber value:12345678} the second one is {key: homeNumber value:098876543}. I am trying to access the information in the metadata section of my blobs container but is giving me nothing. I try to get properties from here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-container-properties-metadata?tabs=dotnet) but following those steps still provides me no value or key.

```
 var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BlobConnection"));

        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("myContainer");

        var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: "myFile.txt");

        foreach (var item in blobs)
        {
            //This prints nothing and the count = to zero
            Console.WriteLine(item.Metadata.Key);
             if(item.Metadata.Key == "cellPhone" {
              //Here goes some logic for my code
             }


        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the metadata, please change the following line of code:

```
var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: "myFile.txt");
```

to

```
var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: "myFile.txt", traits: BlobTraits.Metadata);
```

then you should see metadata populated for the blobs. You can learn more about BlobTraits here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobtraits?view=azure-dotnet.

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed my problem